# How to delete first and last items before the matching pattern or delimiter in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have this vector called `myvec`. I want to delete everything before first delimiter `_` and everything after the last delimiter `_` (including the delimeter). How do I do this in R to get the `result`.

```
myvec <- c("contamination_LPH-001-10_3.txt", "contamination_LPH-001-10_AK1_0.txt", 
"contamination_LPH-001-10_AK2_1.txt", "contamination_LPH-001-10_PD_2.txt", 
"contamination_LPH-001-10_SCC_4.txt")
```

Result:

```
LPH-001-10, LPH-001-10_AK1,LPH-001-10_AK2,LPH-001-10_PD,LPH-001-10_SCC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub` for this

```
gsub("^[^_]*_|_[^_]*$", "", myvec)
#[1] "LPH-001-10"     "LPH-001-10_AK1" "LPH-001-10_AK2" 
#[4] "LPH-001-10_PD"  "LPH-001-10_SCC"
```

From the start (`^`) of the string, we are matching zero or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) followed by a `_` or (`|`) match a `_` followed by zero or more charachters that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) till the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with `""`.

---

Or we can also use capture groups  (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference for the capture groups.

```
sub("^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$", "\\1", myvec)
#[1] "LPH-001-10"     "LPH-001-10_AK1" "LPH-001-10_AK2" 
#[4] "LPH-001-10_PD"  "LPH-001-10_SCC"
```